# Raising Altitude by using Magnetic Torquer and Reaction Wheels

Tags: satellites

Suppose a satellite with a [magnetic torquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer) and [reaction wheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel).
I wonder if it is possible to use both in such a way that the overall effect would be to raise the satellite's altitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The satellite could change its attitude, but not altitude. In order to change altitude the satellite would have to speed itself up, that would require some form of reaction engine.

Comment: Ah right, I always forget that it's all about speed. But what happens if you counter balance the spin from magnetic torquer and reaction wheels? Where does your effort/energy go?

Comment: Dissipated into the ambient magnetic field by the magnetorquer and into heat by friction in the reaction wheels, then radiated via blackbody radiation.

Comment: I suppose you could take advantage of the [Yarkovsky effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky_effect) by rotating in the right direction, and radiating heat backwards. Although that acceleration would be negligible compared to atmospheric drag